# AWK doesn't properly tokenize input as part of git alias

Tags: bash, git, awk

I am trying to add a git alias to prompt me to delete all the local git branches. I have come pretty far an I've arrived at the following:

```
pdb = "! sh -c 'git branch -vv | grep -v \"origin/.*\" | awk \"{print $1}\" | xargs -L1 -I{} -p git branch -D {}' -"
```

The first part will list all branches with verbose output so that when piped to `grep`, we can filter out the branches with a remote counterpart. `awk` should then take the first part of that output, the branch name, and send it off to the `xargs` command. The trouble I am having is that `awk` is passing the entire verbose output to `xargs`.

This answer got me a little closer but I am still not quite getting the expected output from `awk`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25954749/3356508

```
$ git pdb
git branch -D master-test1 9837ec0f0 test commit 1 ?...y
error: branch 'master-test1 9837ec0f0 test commit 1' not found.
git branch -D master-test2 2810823bc test commit 2 ?...y
error: branch 'master-test2 2810823bc test commit 2' not found.
```

Comment: In a `.git/config` file, Git "eats" one level of backslashes, hence the need for `\\ `. Note that in unquoted text, Git also eats/interprets `$`, but that's not the case here. More generally, though, don't use `git branch` for this sort of thing, use `git for-each-ref`, which is aimed at writing scripts. (Not that it matters that much for this particular case, but in general, `git branch` is a porcelain command and `git for-each-ref` is a plumbing command that subsumes both it and `git tag`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot test your issue, but I think it is due the fact that you are not escaping the `$` in awk, so you end up doing a simple print, which, by default, prints everything.

Try with:

```
pdb = "! sh -c 'git branch -vv | grep -v \"origin/.*\" | awk \"{print \\$1}\" | xargs -L1 -I{} -p git branch -D {}' -"
```

Comment: Not quite. `$ git pdb
fatal: bad config line 10 in file X://.gitconfig
`

Comment: It looks like you have a problem with your git configuration, right?

Comment: Yes, after I added the escape character in front of the `$1`

Comment: Is `git branch -vv | grep -v \"origin/.*\" | awk \"{print $1}\"` giving the expected output? This was your issue, so check if now it is tokenizing properly.

Comment: From the command line, I have to use single quotes around `print $1`. For example `git branch -vv | grep -v "origin/.*" | awk '{print $1}'` gives the expected output

Comment: You can also use double quotes if you escape properly the special characters. So, in command line, is `git branch -vv | grep -v "origin/.*" | awk "{print \$1}"` giving also the expected result, right? In that case, your original question is solved, and now you have to tackle a new problem :-)

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out, your initial answer was really close, but I had to use double backslashes, if you update your answer to the following I will accept `pdb = "! sh -c 'git branch -vv | grep -v \"origin/.*\" | awk \"{print \\$1}\" | xargs -L1 -I{} -p git branch -D {}' -"`

Comment: Right, one slash per the double quote in awk, ans another because all of these is inside a string passed to `sh -c`. Didn't realized that detail.

Comment: For your second issue, try to reduce the problem. Probably, if you perform a `git branch -D <branch_name>` you will be able to reproduce the error.